# How to dynamically get bus station from Google Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

My apps use Google's `geofencing API` to detect when User approaching a geofence registered bus station.

Currently i search the bus station `long & lat` manually from the Google Maps and register it to the `geofence`. This is good for testing purpose but will be a trouble when i want to register hundred of stations/places.

Is it possible to get the `long & lat` dynamically from the Google Maps? Please kindly show me the clue.

Is there any specific API/Method to get those complete data?

**Note** : I dont want to get the nearest/stations around the User. My goal is to get the station list regardless of User's location.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Fetching all bus stations everywhere would take a *very* long time and include a lot of data your users will likely never use (you'd also hit the limit on the number of concurrent geofences allowed by an application). As far as I know, there's no way to access such data through Google APIs anyway. A better approach would probably be to preemptively fetch bus station data near to the current user location and just add geofences for those (indexing each geofence using a Place ID so that you can remove it when the user moves into a different geographic area).

The [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) will allow you to search for [places of type `bus_station`](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) near to a given location. You will probably want to use a [Nearby Search Request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). The response to such a request will be a list of results, where each result will include a location. Here's an example of the information included with [each individual result](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses):

```
{
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.870775,
           "lng" : 151.199025
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
     "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
     "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 270,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
           "width" : 519
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "alt_ids" : [
        {
           "place_id" : "D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
           "scope" : "APP"
        }
     ],
     "reference" : "CoQBdQAAAFSiijw5-cAV68xdf2O18pKIZ0seJh03u9h9wk_lEdG-cP1dWvp_QGS4SNCBMk_fB06YRsfMrNkINtPez22p5lRIlj5ty_HmcNwcl6GZXbD2RdXsVfLYlQwnZQcnu7ihkjZp_2gk1-fWXql3GQ8-1BEGwgCxG-eaSnIJIBPuIpihEhAY1WYdxPvOWsPnb2-nGb6QGhTipN0lgaLpQTnkcMeAIEvCsSa0Ww",
     "types" : [ "travel_agency", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Pyrmont Bay Wharf Darling Dr, Sydney"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. How about fetching only specific stations? Is it possible in the API? So maybe i post the stations's names and the API return their lat & lang

Comment: You can try https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests or https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete for text-based queries.